# Webpack compile development version of Vue when watching, compile production when build

Tags: vue.js, webpack

how would I compile the development version of Vue when I run the watch command, but when I run the build I want it to compile the production version.

```
module.exports = {
    mode: 'production',
    entry: [
        './resources/js/vue/app.js'
    ],
    output: {
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        chunkFilename: '[chunkhash].bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'assets/js/vue'),
        publicPath: '/assets/js/vue/'
    },
    resolve: { alias: { vue: "vue/dist/vue.js" } },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                use: 'vue-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    'vue-style-loader',
                    'css-loader',
                    'sass-loader'
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new VueLoaderPlugin(),
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(['./assets/js/vue/*'])
    ]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd strongly suggest using [vue cli](https://cli.vuejs.org/). `vue-cli-service build` compiles for production and `vue-cli-service serve` compiles for development with hot module replacement.

And if you are looking for more comfort, it has also a user interface. You can access vue ui and build or serve with a few clicks.